# Making parts of text bound to each other

Tags: text

I wonder, how do I force parts of text staying on the same page/column together so if there is not enough space all of them would be transferred to another page/column.

In the image you can see the way it is happening at the moment. I want the part of the text in the lower left to be connected with the one in the upper right. Is there a way to force it without manual insertion of \newpage and staff?

[image]

Comment: The `needspace` package may be of use: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/needspace.  Alternatively, you can place text that needs to stay together in a `\vbox`.

Comment: Thanks, the \vbox is exactly what I was looking for. However, LaTex seems to be enlarging spaces between the lines so that the column would fill all the page. Do you know if there is a way to force it just to make a column/page break?